# A question about a function used to define the length of a curve in Riemannian geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let be $(M,g)$ a connected Riemannian manifold.

If $ \phi : [a,b] \rightarrow M$ is $C^\infty$ we define the arc-length of the curve $\phi$ as the quantity:

$$J(\phi )= \int_a^b f(\phi (t),\dot{\phi(t)})\; dt$$ where

$$ f(\phi(t),\dot{\phi(t)})^2= \sum_{\alpha, \beta} g_{\alpha,\beta}(\phi(t)) \:\dot{\phi}(t)^\alpha\: \dot{\phi}(t)^\beta$$
and $\phi^1(t),\dots,
\phi^n(t)$ are the local coordinates of $\phi(t)$.

Why my book says that $f$ is a function with values in $M$, $$f:(a,b) \rightarrow M?$$ I'm confused.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: $f$ has two component, so the domain of $f$ is $TM$, the tangent bundle of $M$.

Comment: @JohnMa perhaps it as an abuse of notation

Comment: The bigger problem is that the image is $\mathbb R$, but not $M$. For the domain , you can just consider $f(\phi(t), \phi'(t))$, so the domain is $(a,b)$. But the image can't be $M$.

Comment: @JohnMa Yes, it does not make sense, probably it is an error of the book. Thank you very much!